# Flutter dev tool not working with version 1.12.13+hotfix.9

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

I am using flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 version when i am going use dev tool in vs code it showing blank tree

[image]

Comment: Stable channel is currently on version 2.10.3. I’d highly suggest updating

Comment: this project is developed with 1.12.13+hotfix.9  so if do it  with latest version then project not run

Comment: That's not true. It doe not mean that if you started your project with 1.12.13 you need to remain on 1.12.13. Keeping you flutter version up-to-date is highly encouraged. The flutter plugin in VSCode keeps updating to work with the latest version. You could try and downgrading that if you feel like you need to keep your current flutter version.